# Using array for Component declaration perpouses

Tags: android

I want to declare Buttons and other components in a different way, wonna decrease my lines of code.
So, I tried this way:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
            EditText[] Items;
            TextView[] Total;
            String[] ids = {"editText1","editText2","textView8","textView7"};
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
                    Items[i]=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ids[i]);`
                }
            }
        }
```

it is not working, do you understand What I wonna do ? Is it possible ?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by isn't working? so you get errors? what is the expected behaviour?

Comment: I just not want to write  
next=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
back=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
others=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
Just a for loop for that, saving them in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R.id.Something` are consts generated automatically.

You could not refer to them by using strings...

You could iterate if you declare them as array of int consts:
`int[] ids = new int[]{R.id.editText1,R.id.editText2,R.id.textView8,R.id.textView7};`

and then
`Items[i]=(EditText)findViewById(ids[i]);`

Comment: "You could not refer to them by using strings..." You actually can (see my answer), but, generally, one might be better off with your suggestion - or even do without that array from the question as it does not really save much code nor improve readability... or nowadays use Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

R.id.someting is actually a int value that you get form R file in your project, like constant value. You can not use it like string. It is a little tricky to find R file in your project if you are beginner, but when you find it you will see that all views in your xml file have int value that you connect via R.id.name .

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I feel like there is one answer missing. You can actually do this exactly as intended by using

```
Resources.getIdentifier(String name, String defType, String defPackage)
```

See details [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

This is discouraged in the documentation as inefficient, so I would not make it a habit, but you may find exceptional situations where it is justified. For instance, I am using it for adding test data in a non-production variant of my app.

So, in your case, it might look something like

```
Items[i]=findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("editText" + i, "id", getPackageName()));
```